# Can str raise exception?

Tags: python

Is there any chance that `str` can raise exception for **non-callable** argument ? Apart of custom classes that could override `__repr__` for some reason ?

I have some argument on enter of function and if it's not `str` I am converting it to it. I'm curious if I have to handle exceptions, and if I have to, which ones ? Handling `Exception` is not good practice but it seems like it's the only way.

Edit:
By no-callable I mean that the argument is not executed inside str, like `str(get_something_to_convert())`. In this example I should handle exceptions in inner function.

Comment: is `get_something_to_convert()` your real function? Or is  `get_something_to_convert` a variable , which can be either a function or something else? I didn't clearly understand your question

Comment: Even for callable arguments, if you're *not actually calling them*, then the only way you can get an error from `str(something)` is if `something.__str__()` (or `.__repr__()`) raises an exception, which would be... somewhat unusual.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it is possible though. `str` doesn't do anything special to swallow them.

Comment: @PeterWood no, that's true; it wouldn't quietly suppress any errors that did occur.

Comment: @AnandSKumar It's only example of that I do not call the argument passed, I convert it as is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any class could override `__str__` for any reason because `str` calls `__str__`, not `__repr__`, if both are defined. IMHO that is, by itself, enough reason to be prepared to get exceptions.

But a common pitfall for non-English users is Unicode strings with Python 2.x. Just look at the following code:

```
>>> a = u'\xe9\xe8'
>>> print a
éè
>>> str(a)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    str(a)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1:
 ordinal not in range(128)
```

So a simple Unicode string containing non-ASCII characters will throw an exception when you call `str` on it.

It is up to you whether you prefer to handle the exception, or document that the function only accepts arguments that can be directly converted to string with `str`.

Comment: Oh, ok Encoding is one of the problems that could occur, I think it will be the only one. I also could not imagine the other example, users are allowed to pass any object as the argument but I think I will simply document it well and handle encoding errors :) Thanks a lot

Comment: By default, I believe `__str__` delegates to `__repr__`. The main exception to that rule being string types, and floats in Python 2.x. ie. `str([]) == repr([])`, but `str("") != repr("")`.